# Set the value of a radio button with the controller in javascript

Tags: lightning, javascript, button, form

I would like to do something simple but I think it is not as simple as I though.
I have a form with a radio button field (salutation field in the account) and I would like to auto fill the value when the page loads itself.

I am not sur if I have to use input:radio or lightning:input.

I need that the button is horizontal, not vertical.

Can you help me please to fill le field with the javascript controller and get the value?

This is my current code:

Component:

```
<aura:attribute name="salutationResult" type="String" default="" />
<aura:attribute name="salutations" type="String[]" default="Mademoiselle, Madame, Monsieur" />

<aura:iteration items="{!v.salutations}" var="aSalutation">
   <ui:inputRadio name="salutation" change="{!c.onRadio}" /> {!aSalutation} &nbsp;&nbsp;
</aura:iteration>
```

Controller:

```
({
    doInit: function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAccountInformations");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.account", storeResponse[0]);
                var civilite = storeResponse[0].Salutation;
                if(civilite != undefined){
                    ? ... ?
                }
            }
        });  

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

onRadio: function(cmp, evt) {
         var selected = evt.getSource().get("v.label");
         cmp.find("salutationResult").set("v.value", selected);
     }
})
```

Regards
Aurélien

Comment: I use lightning:radioGroup but it is not horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

This issue looks like it is purely a styling and missuse of components issue.

If you combine lighning:input components and embed them within lighning:layout items, you can easily achieve a horizontal display of radio button options:

```
<aura:attribute name="salutationResult" type="String" default="" />
  <aura:attribute name="salutations" type="String[]" default="Mademoiselle, Madame, Monsieur" />

  <lightning:layout multipleRows="false">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.salutations}" var="aSalutation">
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
            <lightning:input onchange="{!c.change}" type="radio" label="{!aSalutation}" name="options" value="{!aSalutation}"/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:layout>
```

[image]

Notice that the `multipleRows` attribute is set to false - however, in my test scenario it is not required.

you can equaly set a size to the space each layoutItem will take. you might want to take a look at [Layout Item](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:layoutItem/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleLayoutItemsDefaultSize)

As per getting the field values on change, this is rather trivial, the lighinng:input component has an onchange event which you can use

For Ex:

```
change : function(component, event, helper) {
    const radBtnValue = event.getSource().get('v.value');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

When the page loads itself, how can I check the correct radio button in the controller?

Comment: not sure i understant, you controll what radio button is selected on page load, if you have a separate or 2nd question, feel free to open a new post